# take selected rows from grouped dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following dataframe I want to filter groups and take only selected row from left groups.

```
  state  city  voting_majority_status_fk  other
0     A    A1                          4   True
1     A    A1                          4   True
2     A    A1                          2  False
3     A    A2                          3   True
4     B    B2                          4  False
5     B    B2                          2   True
6     C    C1                          4   True
7     C    C1                          4   True
8     C    C1                          2  False
```

I want to group it and take only one row from the positive groups:

I want my final result be only:

```
2     A    A1                          2  False
8     C    C1                          2  False
```

my code till now:

```
columns = ['state', ' city', 'voting_majority_status_fk', 'other']
        data = [['A', 'A1', 4, True],
                ['A', 'A1', 4, True],
                ['A', 'A1', 2, False],
                ['A', 'A2', 3, True],
                ['B', 'B2', 4, False],
                ['B', 'B2', 2, True],
                ['C', 'C1', 4, True],
                ['C', 'C1', 4, True],
                ['C', 'C1', 2, False],
                ['C', 'C3', 2, False]]

        df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)
        grouped_df = df.groupby(['state', ' city'])
        filtered_data = grouped_df.filter(VotingDataFetcher.my_filter)

@staticmethod
    def my_filter(group):
        if 3 in group.voting_majority_status_fk.unique():
            return False
        if 2 not in group.voting_majority_status_fk.unique():
            return False
        if 4 in group.voting_majority_status_fk.unique():
            majority = group[group.voting_majority_status_fk == 4].head(1)
            if not majority.other.tolist()[0]:
                    return False
            else:
                minority = group[group.voting_majority_status_fk == 2]
                tt = minority.head(1) <= I only want those lines.
                return True
        return False
```

I get following output, I get whole groups but I need only selected rows from groups.

```
0     A    A1                          4   True
1     A    A1                          4   True
2     A    A1                          2  False <= only this one
6     C    C1                          4   True
7     C    C1                          4   True
8     C    C1                          2  False <= and this one
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `apply` with custom function which return `tt`:

```
def my_filter(group):
    vuniq = group.voting_majority_status_fk.unique()
    if (4 in vuniq) and (2 in vuniq) and not (3 in vuniq):
        majority = group[group.voting_majority_status_fk == 4].head(1)
        if majority.other.tolist()[0]:
            minority = group[group.voting_majority_status_fk == 2]
            tt = minority.head(1) #<= I only want those lines.
            return tt

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)
grouped_df = df.groupby(['state', ' city'])
filtered_data = grouped_df.apply(my_filter).reset_index(drop=True)
print (filtered_data)
  state  city  voting_majority_status_fk  other
0     A    A1                          2  False
1     C    C1                          2  False
```

You cannot use `filter`, because it return `True` or `False` per group and it decided if group is removed or not.

You can test it by:

```
filtered_data = grouped_df.apply(my_filter)
print (filtered_data)
state   city
A      A1        True
       A2       False
B      B2       False
C      C1        True
       C3        None
dtype: object
```

Comment: I tried running this function of a 200K lines dataset, and this was extremely slow about 5 minutes. Do you have ideas how I can speed it up ?

Comment: Hard question. I have some idea - filter outside groupy in all df, but now I am only on phone, so I tried something tomorrow.

Comment: I am working on it and it is not easy. I try more things and it seems `filter`  with `groupby` is necessary as first step. Can you check if this is still very slow? `def f(x):`
    `fk = x.voting_majority_status_fk.unique()`
    `return (fk == 4).any() and (fk == 2).any() and not (fk == 3).any()`

`df1 = df.groupby(['state', ' city']).filter(f)` ? What is size of `df1` in your real data?

Comment: I also work on it now with new ideas. the data set is 200K. this is my code till now majority_vp = df[(df.voting_majority_status_fk == 4) & (df.other == True)].vp_fk.unique()
        minority_vp = df[(df.voting_majority_status_fk == 3) & (df.other == False)].vp_fk.unique()
        dvc_vp = numpy.intersect1d(majority_vp, minority_vp, assume_unique=True) started to be really fast.

Comment: Nice, is possible use `majority_vp = df[(df.voting_majority_status_fk == 4) & (df.other)].vp_fk.unique()`
`minority_vp = df[(df.voting_majority_status_fk == 3) & (~df.other)].vp_fk.unique() ` ?

Comment: Another change is `loc` - `majority_vp = df.loc[(df.voting_majority_status_fk == 4) & (df.other), 'vp_fk'].unique() 
minority_vp = df.loc[(df.voting_majority_status_fk == 3) & (~df.other), 'vp_fk'].unique()`. But what is `vp_fk` ? Columns `state` and `city` together? Because your solution is faster as `groupby`...